# Field not showing in the view all details of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, list-form

I have a list on a SharePoint site that is coming from the Content Type Hub. Since I don't know where the content type fields are being used I created a new field on the site list settings and not from the Content Type Hub.

**Problem**:

So that field “Next Date for Review” is a calculated “read only” field which is why it is not showing up in the intake form.

However when you click on the view details for an item on the list the new field is also not appearing it looks like it only appears on the list view?

Comment: How many content types you have in your list?

Comment: If you have Select Yes for "Allow management of content types?" option. This may be a delay problem, you wait a moment, the problem will be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

1. Allow management of content types:

   a. Go to list settings > Advanced settings

   b. Select **Yes** for "Allow management of content types?" option

   c. Click **OK** at the bottom of advanced settings page to save the changes.

   [image]
2. Add column to all content types while creation:

   a. Go to list settings > Columns section and select "Create column"

   b. While creating a calculate column, check **Add to all content types** option

   c. Click **OK** to save the changes and create a column

   [image]

Comment: Above solution should work for you. If it is not working, you have to manually add your calculated column to respective content type from list settings.